# Simple WYSIWYG Textbox ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wysiwyg

I am trying to do some wysiwyg Textbox for specific use, so I don't need usual wysiwyg, I need like buttons which will insert like [ @ or so.

I thought to add some buttons which will insert those to textbox.

Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), which is highly customizable.

The thing you try to do, is not built-in in almost any WYSIWYG editor out there (AMAIK). Thus, you should implement it on your own. But by using a third-party WYSIWYG, and customizing it (instead of creating a WYSIWYG editor entirely from scratch), you can get sure that you already have tens of other functionalities.

Also I should note that most WYSIWYG editors can become as simple as having one toolbar with basic formatting buttons (just like SO's editor).

Comment: +1, one of most known and reliable editor for .NET for a long long time